# sed replacing unwanted part of string

Tags: shell, sed

I want to replace VERSION variable with $version_1 and PROG_VERSION with $version_2 within a same file. I used sed for that

```
sed s/VERSION/$version_1/g | sed s/PROG_VERSION/$version_2/g
```

The problem is sed also replaces a portion of PROG_VERSION with PROG_(value of $version_1).
How should I prevent sed from making unwanted changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is sed also replaces a portion of PROG_VERSION with
>   PROG_(value of $version_1). How should I prevent sed from making
>   unwanted changes.

Use word boundaries in sed to prevent unwanted replacements:

```
sed "s/\bVERSION\b/$version_1/g"
```

OR:

```
sed "s/\<VERSION\>/$version_1/g"
```

**For Mac OSX:** For some strange reason none of above syntax works and you need to use this weird syntax:

```
 sed "s/[[:<:]]VERSION[[:>:]]/$version_1/g"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest would be to switch the order of the commands.

```
sed "s/PROG_VERSION/$version_2/g; s/VERSION/$version_1/g" file
```

Comment: This is definitely how I would have solved it, even if the other way is more elegant.

Comment: However, this will cause issues with `PROG_VERSION_AND_LARGER_SUPER_STRINGS` variables. Matching word boundaries would be more reasonable.